# Top Padding in TinyMce

Tags: php, mpdf

Im using TinyMce to load a template which the user can than fill out.It is later beeing converted to a PDF with MPDF.Right now my problem is that I cant reduce the space between the top of my paper and my text is there any solution for that.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will have little if nothing to do with TinyMCE as you need to tell MPDF to set the margins on the page.

You can specify margins in millimetres in the [MPDF constructor](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=184).

`$margin_left`, etc:

> Sets the page margins for the new document. All values should be
>   specified as LENGTH in millimetres. If you are creating a DOUBLE-SIDED
>   document, the margin values specified will be used for ODD pages; left
>   and right margins will be mirrored for EVEN pages. BLANK or omitted
>   uses the default values.

Comment: Thanks alot spent half a day looking for a way to solve this with TinyMCE stupid me >.<